# Lambda function delayed Kinesis stream processing

Tags: lambda, queue, amazon-kinesis

I'm just wondering whether an delayed stream processing is possible with Kinesis streams? And is this delayed processing possible with Lambda functions?

I'd like to group several interactions of a user over 5 Minutes before closing his session and processing his data. Thus I would write all data of a session into one Kinesis stream partition.

For me right now it is a little bit unclear than Lambda functions are invoced to consume Kinesis streams and how i can adjust the stream consumtion?

Can I adjust stream consumtion by time / data-chunk limits?

Can the consumtion of kinesis partitions be delayed? E.g. wait at least 5 min before partitions are processed.

Comment: Opened an support ticket with AWS. Right now suche a functionality is not available but on feature list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an ideal case for [Kinesis Analytics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/what-is.html).  From their documentation:

> Amazon Kinesis Analytics enables you to quickly author SQL code that
>   continuously reads, processes, and stores data in near real time.
>   Using standard SQL queries on the streaming data, you can construct
>   applications that transform and gain insights into your data.

You could set up an application to read off of your initial Kinesis stream, aggregate the data as needed using a 5 minute window, and then feed it to another Kinesis stream for further processing.

Comment: For now I implemented it with a circular kinesis stream reaggregating and consuming itself till a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Drools Kinesis Analytics. Look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442606/analyze-a-tumbling-window-with-a-lag-in-aws-kinesis-analytics-sql/46645665#46645665) and see the Drools answer.